# Integration of CCDA using Mirth out of CSV files

Tags: mirth, c-cda

I am new to the environment, I am learning. Can you help me to understand the integration for C-CDA Progress note with CSV?

I have tried creating on bridge but data is not updating even after use of JavaScripts.

I tired creating transformation with no success.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VD0Dc.png)